# I'm looking for working example of django mptt

Tags: django, django-mptt

Does anyone has a working example of django mptt. I am not able to implement it.
Maybe category system.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my code, part of an accounting app:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel
from mptt.fields import TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):
    ledger = models.ForeignKey(Ledger)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        'self', null = True, blank = True, default = None,
        related_name = 'children'
    )
    label = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
```

This simply follows the documentation. Which specific part goes wrong for you?